How to make scipy newton_krylov use a different derivative approximation method
After reading the documentation seems like it uses forward difference as its approximation method, but I can't see any direct way to make it use other method or a custom one.
Using the tools in the documentation I tried this to make it use a custom method and did this implementation to test if the results were the same:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import newton_krylov
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator

# Function
def uniform_problem(x, A, b):
    return b - A@x

size = 12

A = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(size, size))
b = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(size, ))

xr = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(size, ))# root
x0 = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(size, ))# initial guess

F = lambda x: uniform_problem(x, A, b) - uniform_problem(xr, A, b)

#Arbitrary parameters
max_iter = 10
tol = 1e-3
h = 1e-4

repeats = 5000

# Using own implementation of Forward Difference

def get_jacobian_vector_product_fdf(F, x, v, h=1e-5):
  step = h * v
  return (F(x + step) - F(x)) / h

error1 = 0
for i in range(repeats):
    x = x0.copy()

    lambdaJv = lambda v: get_jacobian_vector_product_fdf(F, x, v, h)
    linear_operator = LinearOperator((size, size), matvec=lambdaJv)

    solution1 = newton_krylov(F, x, method="gmres", inner_maxiter=max_iter, iter=max_iter, callback=None, f_tol=tol, rdiff=h, inner_M=linear_operator)
    error1 += np.linalg.norm(F(solution1))
error1 /= repeats
print(error1) # aprox 1.659173186802721

# Using no custom method

error2 = 0
for i in range(repeats):
    x = x0.copy()
    
    solution2 = newton_krylov(F, x, method="gmres", inner_maxiter=max_iter, iter=max_iter, callback=None, f_tol=tol, rdiff=h)
    error2 += np.linalg.norm(F(solution2))
error2 /= repeats
print(error2) # aprox 0.024629534404425796

print(error1/error2) # Orders of magnitude of difference

I expected to get the same results, but they are clearly different. I think I'm having trouble understanding what the tools of the documentation do.

Please make a [mcve], update your code with missing parts. We should be able to run your code by copy pasting it.

Done, updated the code.

I misunderstood, the 'inner_M' parameter does not do what I thought it did, but I found a solution by creating a custom scipy Jacobian class following the same implementation scipy does.
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse.linalg
from scipy.linalg import norm
import scipy.optimize._nonlin
from scipy.optimize._nonlin import Jacobian, _nonlin_wrapper

# Create your jacobian class using the scipy Jacobian interface.
class KrylovJacobianCustom(Jacobian):
    #... code of custom jacobian ...
    # (In my case, a variant of the Krylov one)

# Make your class visible to the scipy scope.
scipy.optimize._nonlin.KrylovJacobianCustom = KrylovJacobianCustom

# Define your function using the scipy non linear wrapper.             
newton_krylov_custom = _nonlin_wrapper('newton_krylov_custom', scipy.optimize._nonlin.KrylovJacobianCustom)


This way, this function behaves the same as newton_krylov() or any other non linear solver, but will instead use your implementation of the Jacobian class in the computation.
Example:
def fun(x):
    return [x[0] + 0.5 * x[1] - 1.0, 0.5 * (x[1] - x[0]) ** 2]

sol = newton_krylov_custom(fun, [0, 0])
>> array([0.66731771, 0.66536458])

